# Object is possibly null. TypeScript error (angular typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to add an image file to "convert" function.

this is my code from the component.html for the input:

```
<li>
    <label for="avatarIMG" id="avatarLbL"> image: </label>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" #imageBox name="image" id="avatarinput" (change)="convert($event)">
    <button type="button" id="avatarInputBTN" (click)="imageBox.click()"> Profile Picture </button>
</li>
```

the event suppose to send the values of the object with all of the values + the image file from the form to the component.ts and this is the code of it:

```
public convert(e: Event): void {
    this.eventFiles = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    if (this.eventFiles !== null) {
        this.user.image = this.eventFiles;
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = args => this.preview = args.target?.result?.toString();
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.eventFiles);
    }
}
```

i get an error of object possibly null for (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0].

how can i fix this?..

Comment: I don't use typescript, but probably you need to check `e.target as HTMLInputElement != null` or `e.target is HTMLInputElement` first. before access `.files`

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
this.eventFiles = (e.target as HTMLInputElement)?.files?.[0];
```